# How to execute a conditional alert on OnLoad MVC event

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to use Razor code inside a view section to show an alert if a condition is true. My code is:

```
@Section BodyAttributes
      @If (ViewData("condition") = True) Then
          onLoad = "alert('message')"
      End If
End Section
```

I'm new to MVC world and I don't know how to write this. The comiler complains that onLoad is not declared.
If I remove the condition, the code works fine and the alert box is shown.

Answer (score 2):

Razor views simply generate HTML. That is their only responsibility.

What you're trying to do involves using JavaScript to display an alert dialog to the user with some message: "message".

You've got the JavaScript part down, that's simply `alert('message');`, but you'll need to wrap that in a script tag, and put that script tag in the header of the HTML (arguably).

So, you'd end up having something like this:

```
@section AlertHeaderSection
{   
    @if (ViewData("condition") == true)
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert('message');
        </script>
    }
}
```

Comment: once script tag renders it wont show alert 2nd time if given condition evaluates . any idea how to make alert fire multiple times with no page refresh @Chris .

Comment: As stated in the answer, Razer views are only responsible for generating HTML. If you want to perform logic on the front end you need to use JavaScript. Your question has most likely been answered elsewhere on stackoverflow.

Comment: Well yes true to that I'm aware of it . I had no luck to find a post . As far I see it once JavaScript <script> executed it wont execute again without a page refresh in partial view .

Comment: Quick breakdown: Razor is an HTML rendering engine. It is nothing more than that. It renders once per `View` response, and then returns the HTML to the client. The client (browser) then renders that HTML. In your case, the JavaScript is simply embedded in the HTML and therefore will only execute once per page load (in the browser). This has absolutely nothing to do with the razor view engine whatsoever. If you would like to find out more about reactive programming with JavaScript, I suggest you look in to JavaScript event handlers, and how you can utilize browser events to suit your needs.